# Two functions generate the same lagrangian submanifold if and only if they differ by a locally constant function

Tags: symplectic-geometry

From the book: Symplectic Geometry by Ana Cannas da Silva, page 19. The following statement is claimed, but I don't full understand it, neither know how to prove it on my own.

> Two functions generate the same lagrangian submanifold if and only if they  differ by a locally constant function.

Comment: It's a lot like saying "two functions have the same derivative if and only if they differ by a constant".  (I assume there are already conditions about differentiability of the functions, I don't have the book in front of me to remember which.)  Which terms are you most confused about? i.e. do you know how a function generates a lagrangian submanifold?

E.g. "locally constant" sounds fancy but it really means, constant on each connected component of the manifold they're defined on; usually we have just one connected component and mean a constant function.

Comment: @ElizabethS.Q.Goodman Actually, it was about 'locally constant', thanks Elizabeth.